# How do I use wildcards to redirect/block domains on OS X?

Tags: macos, dns, hosts

I have tried `dnsmasq`, `squid` and [this dns proxy](https://code.google.com/p/marlon-tools/source/browse/tools/dnsproxy/dnsproxy.py), however, none of them does what I want. I want to do something like this:

```
127.0.0.1 *facebook.com
127.0.0.1 *imgur.com
```

Where every URL matched is redirected to `127.0.0.1`, or just straight up blocked. (whether on the command line, on apps, on browsers, simply an emulation of some of the functions of `/etc/hosts` but with wildcards).

Although if nothing works, then via the browser is the most important.

Comment: AFAIK, no version of Unix supports wildcards in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: @G-Man I know, that's why I want some Application to do this.

Comment: Well, then, maybe you should have mentioned `/etc/hosts` fewer than **three** times in your question.  It looks like your question is "What name resolution service will let me do wildcard mapping of host/domain names to IP addresses?"  And that would be off-topic as a product request.

Comment: @Scott The title was misleading ok, but the last says what I want.

Comment: @DisplayName, can you please clarify if you're only trying to use this from the command line or from with apps/browsers? What's the use case and maybe we can direct you towards a better solution. Please update your post with this info

Answer (score 2):

Like Jeremy W. Sherman says, you should consider setting up a localised DNS server, as the `etc/hosts` file cannot support wildcards.

Consider installing a program called [DNSMasq](http://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html), which lets you create a kind of wildcard:

```
address=/facebook.com/127.0.0.1
address=/imgur.com/127.0.0.1
```

Which would reroute all domains with `imgur.com` and `facebook.com` in them to `127.0.0.1`.

Read this blog post titled [/etc/hosts Bugs, and DNS Resolution](http://www.justincarmony.com/blog/2011/07/27/mac-os-x-lion-etc-hosts-bugs-and-dns-resolution/) or this updated blog post: [How to get .dev addresses on Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite in 5 simple steps](http://inkandfeet.com/how-to-get-dev-addresses-on-mac-os-x-1010-yosemite-in-5-simple-steps) for more information on how to install this and why this happens.

Comment: If you read my question you would have seen that I tried to install `dnsmasq`. I tried 8 different guides but none of them worked.

Comment: @DisplayName see my update

Answer (score 0):

Browser:

- Install something like [RequestPolicy](https://requestpolicycontinued.github.io/). (RequestPolicy is Firefox-only as far as I know. I believe uBlock or uMatrix might be able to do something similar for Chrome.)
- Open Manage Policies.
- Add a Block policy:

  - Leave the origin fields empty. (This implicitly matches all origins.)
  - In the destination fields, set the host to a wildcard like `*.facebook.com`.
  - Hit the "Add Rule" button.

[image: Screenshot: Configuring RequestPolicy Continued to block requests to Facebook]

DNS:

- You'll want to run a full-on DNS server like named or unbound and configure System Preferences to use it as your system's DNS server.
- You should be able to configure that to pretend to be authoritative for the entire facebook.com zone and then set up a wildcard within the zone configuration.
- For stuff you don't want to block, you'll configure it to act as a local cache of some upstream DNS server.
- This configuration is hinted at in the [unbound documentation](https://unbound.net/documentation/unbound.conf.html) for its `local-data` configuration stanza:

  > If  you  need more complicated authoritative data, with referrals,
  >   **wildcards,** CNAME/DNAME support, or DNSSEC  authoritative  service,
  >   setup  a  stub-zone  for  it  as detailed in the stub zone section
  >   below. (emphasis added)

Running your own DNS server can get involved. [Here is a walkthrough for setting up named for similar purposes.](http://www.height8.com/info/os/osx/named)

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo nano -e /etc/hosts` to open the hosts file and put inside

```
127.0.0.1 *.domain-name.com #Block subdomains
127.0.0.1 domain-name.com #Block domain
```

You should put both to block the web site.